# Edge Browser can't detect custom checkboxes

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, angular-reactive-forms

I've created custom radio buttons that are essentially checkboxes with added logic to make them function like radio buttons. When the user makes their selection the submit button is suppose to enable. It's working fine on all browsers expect Edge and IE11. The radio buttons are toggling as you would expect, but Edge and IE can't detect them because my submit button remains disabled.

I've looked at [tutorials](https://www.triplet.fi/blog/problem-solved-custom-checkbox-not-working-on-edge/) that are suppose to make it work, but so far no luck. I'm using Reactive Forms and I'm dynamically generating my form. I had trouble using generic radio buttons with the form so that's why I opted to use checkboxes that function like radio buttons. I'm looking for the simplest fix. Either figuring out how to make IE11 and Edge detect them so I can submit my form or using radio buttons that work with my dynamic Reactive Form.

```
                   <section
                        class="table__row"
                        *ngFor="let preference of communicationPref.preferences">
                        <div class="table__row__question">
                            <p class="t-data t-bold">{{preference.display_text}}</p>
                            <p class="t-caption">{{preference.description}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let option of preference.options; let i = index">
                            <div
                                *ngIf="!preference.select_many; else oneOption"
                                class="table__cell">
                                <div class="u-maxXY u-flex u-justifyCenter">
                                    <input
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        class="input input--checkbox"
                                        ngDefaultControl
                                        [formControl]="contactPreferencesForm.get(['communication', 'preferences']).controls[i]">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                           // these are the radio buttons
                            <ng-template #oneOption> 
                                <div class="table__cell">
                                    <div class="u-maxXY u-flex u-justifyCenter">
                                        <label>
                                            <input
                                                type="checkbox"
                                                class="input input--radio"
                                                name="checkbox"
                                                ngDefaultControl
                                                [formControl]="contactPreferencesForm.get(['communication', 'preferences']).controls[i]"
                                                (click)="selectUserPreference(i)">
                                            <input
                                                class="input input--radio"
                                                type="hidden"
                                                name="checkbox"
                                                value="">
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ng-template>
                        </ng-container>
                    </section>
```

// initialize form

```
        this.communicationPref['preferences'].forEach((preference) => {

            const communication_preferences = this.contactPreferencesForm.get('communication') as FormGroup;
            communication_preferences.addControl('preferences', new FormArray([]));
            const cp_array = this.contactPreferencesForm.get(['communication', 'preferences']) as FormArray;

            preference.options.forEach((option, i) => {
                cp_array.push(new FormControl(null));

                if (!!option.name) {
                    this.allPreferences.push(option.name);
                }
            });
        });
```

// make checkboxes function like radio buttons

```
selectUserPreference(choice) {
    if (!!this.communicationPref) {
        this.communicationPref['preferences'].forEach((preference) => {
            if (!!preference.select_many) {

                this.contactPreferencesForm.reset();

                const formValue = this.contactPreferencesForm.get(['communication', 'preferences']).value;
                formValue[choice] = true;

                this.contactPreferencesForm.get(['communication', 'preferences'])
                    .patchValue(formValue);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to use F12 developer tools to check whether there has some error? And try to set break point to check the value, whether it is correct or not. Besides, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I appreciate the tip, I'll look over that document and try to make my question better for next time. I decided to just fix the radio buttons instead of the hacking it. Thank you.

Comment: According to [the tutorial](https://www.triplet.fi/blog/problem-solved-custom-checkbox-not-working-on-edge/) you looked at, I think you could try to use JQuery is () method to check whether the checkbox is checked or not, please refer to [this sample](https://codepen.io/Dillion121/pen/ExxmdLQ).